# How to apply if statement to calcuate integer value inside a group question in Enketo(KoboToolbox)?

Tags: xls, odk

I am building a survey form through KoboToolbox. The web forms are Enketo based. I have some questions of the following type (before comma is first column and first row is data titles in XLSform format):

```
type, name

begin_group,    group_farmexpenses_q5

note,   group_farmexpenses_q5_note

integer,    group_farmexpenses_q5_p1

text,   group_farmexpenses_q5_column_1

end_group,  

begin_group,    group_farmexpenses_q5_1

note,   group_farmexpenses_q5_1_note

integer,    group_farmexpenses_q5_1_p1

text,   group_farmexpenses_q5_1_column_1

end_group,
```

What i want to do is apply if statement for the integer values inside these two groups, however I get error. Here is what I do to apply if-statement :

if(${group_farmexpenses_q5_p1}=999, 0, ${group_farmexpenses_q5_p1})
if(${group_farmexpenses_q5_1_p1}=999, 0, ${group_farmexpenses_q5_1_p1})

since the above are calculate statements and each one is referred to as "expense1" and "expense2"

i then just add them

> ${expense1} + ${expense2}

I get error message:

> if({group_farmexpenses_q5_1_p1} = 999, 0,
> /model/instance[1]/data/group_wx0mk24/group_farmexpenses_q5_1/group_farmexpenses_q5_1_p1
> ), message: The expression is not a legal expression. (line:
> undefined, character: undefined)

Any ideas how to fix this? I think there should be an easy fix but I don't know much about XLSform structures.

Comment: I found a solution through online search. instead of first conditoning and then adding, both can be done in one step: if(${fexp_q1} = 999, 0, ${fexp_q1}) + if(${fexp_q2} = 999, 0,  ${fexp_q2})

Comment: Glad you found a solution. I think your original had a syntax error. Maybe a forgotten $ character.

Answer (score 0):

Proposed solution through online search for @Ziaw. Instead of first conditioning and then adding, both can be done in one step:

calculated data field compute this

> if(${fexp_q1} = 999, 0, ${fexp_q1}) + if(${fexp_q2} = 999, 0,
> ${fexp_q2})